# Generator printing null before the intended output

Tags: java, random, initialization, concatenation

I've created a random word generator and it seems to work pretty well except for the fact that before the desired output, in the same line, it prints "null". 
Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class wordGenerator {

private static String r,s;

public static void randChar(int x) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    x = rand.nextInt((26 - 1) + 1) + 1;

    switch(x) {
    case 1: r = "a"; break;
    case 2: r = "b"; break;
    case 3: r = "c"; break;
    case 4: r = "d"; break;
    case 5: r = "e"; break;
    case 6: r = "f"; break;
    case 7: r = "g"; break;
    case 8: r = "h"; break; 
    case 9: r = "i"; break;
    case 10: r = "j"; break;
    case 11: r = "k"; break;
    case 12: r = "l"; break;
    case 13: r = "m"; break;
    case 14: r = "n"; break;
    case 15: r = "o"; break;
    case 16: r = "p"; break;
    case 17: r = "q"; break;
    case 18: r = "r"; break;
    case 19: r = "s"; break;
    case 20: r = "t"; break;
    case 21: r = "u"; break;
    case 22: r = "v"; break;
    case 23: r = "w"; break;
    case 24: r = "x"; break;
    case 25: r = "y"; break;
    case 26: r = "z"; break;
    default: r = "|null|";
    }

    if(x != 1 && x != 5 && x != 9 && x != 15 && x != 21) {
        int h = rand.nextInt(4 - 0);
        if(h == 2) {
            int k = rand.nextInt(6 - 0);
            switch(k) {
            case 1: r = "a"; break;
            case 2: r = "e"; break;
            case 3: r = "i"; break;
            case 4: r = "o"; break;
            case 5: r = "u"; break;
            }
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Random rand = new Random();
    int y = rand.nextInt((10 - 4) + 1) + 4;

    for(int z = 1; z < y; z++) {
        randChar(0);
        s = s + r;
    }

    System.out.println(s);
}
```

To me it seems fine, but when I think it should output something like

> opfruvme

it prints

> nullopfruvme

What's the problem?

Comment: Does it print `nullopfruvme` or `|null|opfruvme`? And by the way - `(26 - 1) + 1` is 26.

Comment: `nullopfruvme`.

Comment: First things first, all of your cases is bad code design. You should convert the number to ASCII directly. r = (char) x + 96

Comment: I modified my previous comment. You wanna use an ASCII lookup table to convert from integers to characters are vice-versa.
Almost always, you can avoid typing long lists of cases like that. It generally represents a hole in your programming knowledge so it's always worth researching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't initialize `s`.

```
private static String r,s="";
```

When you start your application in the loop the statement `s = s + r;` takes `null` value before concatenating with `r` in the first cycle. Initializing variable with empty string will give you result that you have been expected.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize `s`, so then the first time the `s = s + r;` line executes the current value of `s` (`null`) will be coerced to a String, so you will assign `"null" + r` to `s`.